# HibernateException when validating mapping to MATERIALIZED VIEW in postgresql 9.3

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, materialized-views

How can I map object to materialized view and keep `<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>`?

When launch webapp, I get this exception on startup:

`Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: subjects_lp
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:1302)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:512)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1797)
    ...`

According to sources, it looks like hibernate asks only for types "VIEW" and "TABLE" in DatabaseMetadata#getTableMetadata, while postgresql stores it like "MATERIALIZED VIEW" (checked with plain jdbc).

Surprisingly, I couldn't find in google some info about this error. Is there way to keep hibernate validation on startup, maybe there is way to keep one table/entity unvalidated?

Hibernate version: 4.2.12.Final
Postgresql driver: 9.3-1101-jdbc41

Entity doesn't have any specific annotation, only

`@javax.persistence.Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "table_name", schema = "schema")`

Comment: Looks like it's driver problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a driver problem, it's a hibernate bug.

See this bug
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9602

Answer (score 2):

For those coming here using spring-boot-starter-data-jpa and using `ddl-auto: validate` in  their application.yml file, you'll need to add `hibernate.hbm2dll.extra_physical_table_types: "MATERIALIZED VIEW"` to your properties:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    ~~~
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
    ~~~
    properties:
      hibernate:
        ~~~
        hbm2dll:
          extra_physical_table_types: "MATERIALIZED VIEW"
```

I mention this because it took me a number of tries to get that put in the right place.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I needed, but for some reason this info is not easy to find.

Comment: This didn't work for me as I have a plain old 'view' and I could not find alternative values that would work instead of "MATERIALIZED VIEW" such as "VIEW" Is there a place where those valid literals are listed?  The @ Subselect instead of @ Table worked for me to pass the 'validate' rule.